# Bitcoin transaction location

Tags: blockchain, exchanges

I transferred my Bitcoin from my Exodus desktop wallet to another location. How can I find out, if possible, the exchange I sent it to that has my account? Is there any way to see the transaction code to find out what exchange my BTC is sitting on? Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

> **Is there any way to see the transaction code to find out what exchange my BTC is sitting on?**

You cannot identify an exchange from a transaction-ID.

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure what information you want from the adress you send your bitcoin to but you can see your transaction by using the adress of the bitcoin you send to.

you have to copy the adress you send it to, something like "1CK6KHY6MHgYvmRQ4PAafKYDrg1ejbH1cE" past it on a website like https://blockexplorer.com and then you will have some information for this adress

" Addresses are not wallets nor accounts, and do not carry balances. They only receive funds, and you do not send "from" an address at any time. Various confusing services and software display bitcoins received with an address, minus bitcoins sent in random unrelated transactions as an "address balance", but this number is not meaningful: it does not imply the recipient of the bitcoins sent to the address has spent them, nor that they still have the bitcoins received. "

more information here: https://en.bitcoin.it/wiki/Address

Comment: I sent it to another account I own. I have no idea what account that is. How to find out if this can be accomplished?

Comment: How do you own this another account, is this a wallet, an exchange ? the only thing that make you own an account on bitcoin is the private key, and  How did you find the adress you have to sent the bitcoin to ?